# Is it a defect in basic.def.odr section

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

```cpp
struct S { static const int x = 0; };
int main(){
  S obj;
  int v = obj.x;
}
```

Consider the above code, Is `obj.x` an odr-use?  According to look at the section of [basic.def.odr#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr#3)

> A variable x whose name appears as a **potentially-evaluated expression** ex is odr-used by ex unless applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to x yields a **constant expression** that does not invoke any non-trivial functions and, if x is an object, **ex is an element of the set of potential results of an expression e**, where either the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to **e**, or e is a discarded-value expression.

We have such analysis as the following:

In my code, the variable name is x, which is the x in the above quote, and the expression `obj.x` is the ex in the quote. So, Is `obj.x` a **potentially-evaluated expression**? Yes, It is, because of this:

> An expression is potentially evaluated unless it is an unevaluated operand or a subexpression thereof.

`obj.x` is neither an unevaluated operand or a subexpression thereof. So `obj.x` is a potentially-evaluated expression. And applying the lvalue-to-rvalue `x` indeed yields a constant expression because it's initialized by `0`. What I doubt is the following, that is,

> and, if x is an object, ex is **an element of the set of potential results** of an expression **e**

we assume the e is `obj.x` because lvalue-to-rvalue conversion will apply to it. And what's the set of potential results of e? As following:
[basic.def.odr#2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr#2)

> The set of potential results of an expression e is defined as follows:
>
> > - If e is a **class member access expression**, the set contains the potential results of the **object expression**.

Because e is a class member access expression. hence its set of potential results is object expression.

[expr.ref#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.ref#3)

> Abbreviating postfix-expression.id-expression as E1.E2, E1 is called the object expression.

So, the object expression here is `obj`, hence the set of potential results of expression `obj.x` contains `obj`. Obviously, here ex is x`and if e is`obj.x`then its set of potential results of expression would be`obj`.  So, what the expression` e`of which the ex`x` is a element of set of potential results? According to look at [basic.def.odr#2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr#2), I find nothing.

I only pretty sure the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to `obj.x` whole expression. However, all [compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/3M3vE8) all agree the use of `obj.x` is none odr-use. Is it a defect in the standard?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216595/discussion-on-question-by-jack-x-is-it-a-defect-in-basic-def-odr-section).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t rely on a compiler to tell you whether it’s an odr-use; if it is, and you haven’t defined the variable, the program is ill-formed, **no diagnostic required**.  That said, it seems like this was a defect in C++17 in that the possibility of referring to a static member variable with a class member access (as opposed to a *qualified-id*) was overlooked.

Comment: Yes, it's a defect, because the wording has been modified ,see [basic.def.odr#2.4](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#2.4), however, it's still a defect about 'S::x', because the set of potential result of e  for such case is not clear.

Comment: _That said, it seems like this was a defect in C++17_ Namely, CWG2353.

Comment: @jackX: I’m not sure I see the remaining defect: as strange as it seems, the *id-expression* of a class member access is considered an operand (see [expr.prim.id.dtor]/2; there’s no formal definition) and is thus a subexpression that is considered separately by the potential-result rules.

Comment: @DavisHerring IIUC the concern here that qualified-id `S::x` is not [name](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.pre#def:name), when [basic.def.odr]/4 says [A variable x whose name appears **as** a potentially-evaluated expression E](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.def.odr#4) (maybe `s/as/in/` would resolve this).

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: The term “name” is used with an unfortunate variety of meanings, but I think it’s not very productive to scrutinize it in the context of odr-use.  P1787 will fix this along with all the rest.